# How to set the metadata of file using Drive API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-drive-api, jwt

I'm looking for a solution to uploading the files with some 
specific metadata! I tried to set canDownload to false, but there is no reflection in the result! And I want to set the file to Everybody can access.
Here is my code:

```
const jwToken = new google.auth.JWT(
            token.client_email,
            null,
            token.private_key,
            ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"],
            null
        );

        jwToken.authorize((err : any) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Authentication Success!");
            }
        });

 const metaData = {
            'name': filename,
            "shared": true,
            "capabilities" : {
                    "canDownload": false
            },
            parents: [folderId]
        };

        const media = {
            mimeType: 'Application/Pdf',
            body: fileSystem.createReadStream(pathSystem.join(path))
        };

        drive.files.create({
            auth     : jwToken,
            resource : metaData,
            media    : media,
            fields   : 'id'
        }, (err : any, file : any) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("coming!!");

                throw err;
            } else {
                console.log("File Upload Successfully!");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

- You don't want to make users download the created file.
- You want to share with anyone as reader.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.

  - Your script is typescript. And you build it and run it with Node.js.
- You have already been able to create a file to Google Drive using Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Modification points:

#### About `capabilities`:

Unfortunately, the property of `capabilities.canDownload` is not `writable`. By this, as a method, how about using `copyRequiresWriterPermission`? Using this, the file is set as "Disable options to download, print and copy for commenters and viewers".

#### About `shared`:

The property of `shared` is also not `writable`. So when you want to share with anyone as reader, please use the method of Permissions: create in Drive API.

### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
const metaData = {
           'name': filename,
           "shared": true,
           "capabilities" : {
                   "canDownload": false
           },
           parents: [folderId]
       };

       const media = {
           mimeType: 'Application/Pdf',
           body: fileSystem.createReadStream(pathSystem.join(path))
       };

       drive.files.create({
           auth     : jwToken,
           resource : metaData,
           media    : media,
           fields   : 'id'
       }, (err : any, file : any) => {
           if (err) {
               console.log("coming!!");

               throw err;
           } else {
               console.log("File Upload Successfully!");
           }
       });
```

#### To:

```
const metaData = {
  name: filename,
  parents: [folderId],
  copyRequiresWriterPermission: true
};

const media = {
  mimeType: "application/pdf",
  body: fileSystem.createReadStream(pathSystem.join(path))
};
drive.files.create(
  {
    auth: jwToken,
    resource: metaData,
    media: media,
    fields: "id"
  },
  (err: any, file: any) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    const fileId = file.data.id;
    console.log(fileId);
    const body = {
      auth: jwToken,
      fileId: fileId,
      requestBody: {
        role: "reader",
        type: "anyone"
      }
    };
    drive.permissions.create(body, (err: any, res: any) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(res.data);
    });
  }
);
```

- In order to not make users download the uploaded file, `copyRequiresWriterPermission: true` is added to the request body of Files: create.
- In order to share with anyone, `{role: "reader", type: "anyone"}` is used to the request body of Permissions: create.

### Note:

- In your script, the service account is used. So if you want to see the uploaded file in your Google Drive, please share it with your Google account. By this, you can see it using your browser. Please be careful this.

### References:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Yep, it's working! Thanks for your Help, Your Detailed explanation helps me to resolve the problem easily... By using service account uploading, Files are visible in my browser but deleting the file not working in browser which been uploaded by service account ...........

Comment: @Aadarsh velu Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @Aadarsh velu I apologize for the inconvenience. From `Yep, it's working! Thanks for your Help, Your Detailed explanation helps me to resolve the problem easily`, I had understood your issue was resolved. If my understanding is not correct, please tell me. I would like to modify it.